# ¿cómo puedo declarar las variables especificas que quiero mostrar en una tabla de correlativas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mi BDD contiene una tabla materias donde tengo un cod_materia como clave primaria, entre otros datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la intención de gestionar con esta tabla otra que nace de las rellaciones que pueda tener una materia y sus correlativas, por correlativas me refiero a aquellas que se deben rendir y aprobar capara poder rendir la siguiente. Esta es mi tabla de correlativas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi intencion es mostrar, por medio de una consulta SQL, el nombre de la materia que posee las correlativas, su código, además de el código de la materia correlativa y su correspondiente nombre también:
ej: correlativas.cod_materiaFK , materias.nombre materia, correlativas.cod_materia_correlativa_FK, materias.nombre_materian

en caso de saber qué materias debo rendir y aprobar antes de poder cursas PROGRAMACION I, debería quedar algo así:
correlativas.cod_materiaFK ( 7 ), materias.nombre_materia (PROGRAMACION I), correlativas.cod_materia_correlativa_FK(1), materias.nombre_materian (INTRODUCCION A LA PROGRAMACION)

Pero con esta consulta no obtengo nada:
SELECT correlativas.cod_materia_FK, materias.nombre_mat, correlativas.materia_correlativa_FK, materias.nombre_mat FROM materias INNER JOIN correlativas ON((correlativas.cod_correlativa = correlativas.cod_correlativa) AND (correlativas.materia_correlativa_FK <> correlativas.cod_materia_FK ) AND (materias.nombre_mat <> 'PROGRAMACION I') AND(materias.cod_materia= 7))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y con esta consulta, obtengo una redundancia de datos:

SELECT correlativas.cod_materia_FK,materias.nombre_mat , correlativas.materia_correlativa_FK, materias.nombre_mat FROM materias 
   INNER JOIN correlativas ON( (correlativas.cod_correlativa = correlativas.cod_correlativa)AND(correlativas.materia_correlativa_FK <> correlativas.cod_materia_FK )AND(materias.cod_materia= 7) )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, si alguien tiene alguna idea que pueda aportar, le agradecería mucho que me iluminara!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés 3 tablas lógicas: 1) materias, 2) correlativas, y 3) materias correlativas. 1 y 3 son la misma tabla; para distinguirlas hay que usar alias.

Vamos a llamar `m` a la tabla de materias, `c` a la tabla que relaciona una materia con su correlativa, y `mc` a la tabla de materias correlativas (que es la misma tabla de materias, pero usada con otro propósito). Entonces:

```
select m.cod_materia,   /* también podría ser c.cod_materia_FK, es lo mismo */
       m.nombre_mat,
       mc.cod_materia,  /* o c.materia_correlativa_FK, es lo mismo */
       mc.nombre_mat
from CORRELATIVAS c     /* partimos de la tabla que relaciona */
     inner join MATERIAS m on m.cod_materia = c.cod_materia_FK
                        /* por un lado, buscamos la materia, y... */
     inner join MATERIAS mc on mc.cod_materia = c.materia_correlativa_FK
                        /* por el otro, en otra instancia de la tabla materias,
                           llamada "mc", buscamos la materia correlativa */
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó excelente! utilice ese código y agregue la discriminación por la materia especifica de la cual busco la correlativa. Quedó así:     SELECT m.cod_materia, 
    m.nombre_mat, 
    c.materia_correlativa_FK, 
    mc.nombre_mat 
    FROM correlativas AS c 
    INNER JOIN materias AS m ON (m.cod_materia = c.cod_materia_FK AND m.nombre_mat= 'PROGRAMACION I') 
    INNER JOIN materias AS mc ON (mc.cod_materia = c.materia_correlativa_FK )